# Excel Vba - Type Mismatch Error using parameters

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, excel

I'm trying to switch my code to use parameters. I'm getting a Type Mismatch error on the cmd.Execute rs line. I figured it would be my variables no matching up with what they are in access but I've checked and made sure that everything is the same.

```
    Public Sub AddProducts()

'Initialize all variables
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim stDB As String, stSQL As String, stSQLTwo As String, stProvider As String
Dim linkOID As Integer
Dim linkPID As Integer


stDB = "Data Source= " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\obsDatabase.accdb"
stProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

'Opening connection to database
With cn

    .ConnectionString = stDB
    .Provider = stProvider
    .Open

End With

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

'Get OrderID to link to products
stSQL = "SELECT OrderID FROM Orders WHERE OrderNumber = " & txtOrderNum & ""

rs.Open stSQL, cn

linkOID = rs("OrderID").Value

rs.Close

'Get SupplierID to link to products
stSQL = "SELECT SupplierID FROM Suppliers Where SupplierName = '" & cboxCompName & "'"

rs.Open stSQL, cn

linkPID = rs("SupplierID").Value

rs.Close

stSQL = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName = '" & cboxItemNum & "'"
rs.Open stSQL, cn

If rs.EOF Then

    'Link all product information together
    stSQL = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductUnit, SupplierID) " & _
            "Values (paramItemNum, paramDesc, paramUnit, paramPID)"

    cmd.CommandText = stSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    With cmd

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramItemNum", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, cboxItemNum)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramDesc", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDescription)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramUnit", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtUnit)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("paramPID", adInteger, adParamInput, , linkPID)

    End With

    cmd.Execute rs

End If

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are ItemNum and Unit really text in the database?

Comment: Yeah Some Item numbers have letters in them and Unit refers to how they are sold. (Kits, Boxes, Each, etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pulled out these 3 lines from your code:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.Execute rs
```

`Command.Execute` accepts 3 optional arguments: RecordsAffected; Parameters; Options.  None of those can be a `Recordset`.  You get type mismatch error because you're not feeding `cmd.Execute` a suitable argument.

Comment: I removed the rs argument after the execute and it worked. I wasn't sure about the arguments for the execute command. Thanks HansUp, and Remou for the help